# "Same old, same old"

Tags: meaning, idioms

"It is the same old, same old style."

In this sentence, what kind of phrase is *same old same old*? Is it a adjective?

Comment: I suppose you mean "same old, same old". "Same ,old same old" makes no sense.

Comment: can you not look this up in 5 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, "same old, same old" is a reduplication, a repetition for the purpose of emphasis. It is an idiom, and is usually used alone, e.g. You know. *Same old same old.* (or, *It's the same old same old.*) As such, I suppose it could be two adjectives, repeated. It means *same old thing*.

The etiology is unclear. The [usage](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/06/same-old-same-old.html) first showed up in the 1970s in American black English, according to Cassell’s Dictionary of Slang.

In “Bamboo English,” a 1955 article in the journal American Speech, Arthur M. Z. Norman suggests that samo, samo originated in the Japanese tendency to use reduplication when speaking pidgin English.

However, in *A New Voyage Round the World* (1703), by explorer William Dampier:

> “They (the people of Mindanao) would always be praising the English, as declaring that the English and Mindanaians were all one. This they exprest by putting their two fore-fingers close together, and saying that the English and Mindanaians were samo, samo, that is, all one.”

In a 2001 posting to the Linguist List, Douglas G. Wilson states that samo, samo may have been coined not by the Japanese but by US soldiers – as baby talk the GIs used in an attempt to communicate, repeating each word slowly, with ‘o’ on the end: *same-o, same-o*.

---

*- in for a dime, in for a dollar*.

Comment: Bamboo English! _Eats shoots and leaves_ ?

Answer (score -1):

"same old, same old" is an adjective, a somewhat whimsical way of describing something as old-fashioned, boring or ancient.

Comment: No. It is used to describe something that has stayed the same. It does not have to be old fashioned. The Boring part is correct. _So how is your iPhone App writing job going? Ah, same old, same old_

Comment: Funny, that's pretty much the same thing. If your writing job is "same old, same old", it sounds pretty boring if you ask me :)

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily old fashioned or ancient. PS: Not my downvote

Comment: I gave three possible meanings. I'm pretty sure I've seen or heard this phrase used in all three senses at different times. Don't have any citations to hand though.

Comment: If used as a stand-alone expression (as it usually is), it's a sentence substitute. I suppose the question it's used to answer decides POS if one deems that a useful exercise – with mplungjan's example, that would be _adverbial_. Though doubtless some would claim it's an adjectival, as they know exactly what the expression is a shortening of.